# groupby resulting dataframe concatenation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset looking like that:

```
number   day        hour
12       20180101   10
7        20180101   10
8        20180101   11
78       20180101   12
```

And I would like to get a new dataframe grouping by day,hour, having a sum of number so the result look like :

```
time         amount
2018010110   19
2018010111    8
2018010112   78
```

To do that I am writing the following:

```
new_df['amount'] = df.groupby(['day','hour'])['number'].agg('sum')
```

The result i get is 
But then day and hour seems to be sub keys of number. How can I transform `new_df` so it only have the desired columns ?

If I try to access `new_df['day']` or `new_df['amount']['day']` I get error that the key does not exist.

If i could access it I would run something like

```
new_df['time'] = new_df.... .map(str) + new_df... .map(str)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [24]: df['day_hour'] = df['day'].astype(str)+df['hour'].astype(str)

In [27]: wd.groupby(['day_hour'],as_index=False)['number'].sum()
Out[27]: 
     day_hour  number
0  2018010110      19
1  2018010111       8
2  2018010112      78
```

Comment: ok thanks, but how do I access day_hour and the sum independantly ?

Comment: nice! as_index is what I missed! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
In [160]: df.groupby(df.day * 100 + df.hour)['number'].sum()
Out[160]:
2018010110    19
2018010111     8
2018010112    78
Name: number, dtype: int64
```

---

```
In [164]: (df.groupby(df.day * 100 + df.hour)['number'].sum()
             .rename_axis('time', 0).reset_index(name='amount'))
Out[164]:
         time  amount
0  2018010110      19
1  2018010111       8
2  2018010112      78
```

Comment: rename_axis then reset_index, that's what I was missing! Thanks a lot